# Sorting NSFetchedResultsController items alphabetically but prioritize specific items in Swift and Coredata

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, core-data

I have a method that will fetch a batch of categories from persistent storage. I have added a sort descriptor that sorts the results alphabetically by name (attribute), which works perfectly. But I have 1 item that I would like to show up on top of the list which is "Uncategorized" and another one that I want to show at the bottom of the list which is "Other category". Can anyone help me on how I can pull this off?

What I've tried so far is add another sort descriptor to sort the items by "priority". Priority is an Int16 attribute in the Categories entity. But that didn't achieve what I wanted.

Here's the code to the method.

```
    private func fetchCategories(predicate: NSPredicate, sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]) -> NSFetchedResultsController<Category> {
    let fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Category>
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Category> = Category.fetchRequest()

    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
    
    //fetch
    fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    
    do {
        try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        return fetchedResultsController
    } catch {
        debug.log(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    return fetchedResultsController
}
```

And here's the code calling that method:

```
    func categories(ofType type: TransactionType) -> NSFetchedResultsController<Category> {
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "tType == %@ || tType == \(TransactionType.none.rawValue)", "\(type.rawValue)")
    let nameSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    
    let fetchedCategories = fetchCategories(predicate: predicate, sortDescriptors: [nameSort])
    
    return fetchedCategories
}
```

**Update:**

The priority + name sort solution did not work for me because I think the alphabetical takes precedence. Here's an example case.

**Category name -> Priority**

Travel -> 4

Food -> 3

Other category -> 255

Entertainment -> 1

Uncategorized -> 0

**Expected result**

Uncategorized

Entertainment

Food

Travel

Other category

**Actual result**

Entertainment

Food

Other category

Travel

Uncategorized

So basically, I wanted the ordering that's shown in the expected results above. Where Uncategorized, having a priority of 0 will be shown first, and the Other category item is shown last, having a priority of 255. Everything in between should be in alphabetical order.

Comment: What was wrong about the `priority` sort descriptor solution?

Comment: I just updated my post above. I've added a case to explain why the priority sort descriptor solution didn't work.

Comment: Looks like you have name as the first sort key, then priority.  If you switch those around (priority first, then name), I think you will get closer to what you want.  But still not sure it will do exactly what you need - unless priority is contrived to ensure the names are in alphabetical order.

Comment: In addition to @pbasdf's comment, if you could keep the priority of other categories same, that should work.

Comment: @Luckystars This seemed to have worked. The reason why I had different values for priority is that I wanted to give an option for users to re-order the items later on. But that's a problem for another time. Thanks for your help!